# How do I set an image background to a JPanel with BorderLayout?

Tags: java

Basically I'm trying to set an image background for a `JPanel` that uses the `BorderLayout`.

---

The result is that the background is applied (with correct spacing) onto the `LINE_END` section only.

How can I make it apply to all sections?

The code:

```
public class DeckSheet extends JPanel {
    private JButton pack = new JButton();
    private JButton delt = new JButton();

    @Override
      protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        ImageIcon bgImage = new ImageIcon("./Pictures/DeckBack2.png");
        Image bg = bgImage.getImage();
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, null);
    }

    public DeckSheet(String DName){
        setSize(550,100);
        setBackground(null);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());      

        pack.setText(DName);
        pack.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
        pack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //Filling this in later 
            }
        });

        add(pack,BorderLayout.LINE_START);

        JPanel JP = new JPanel();
        JP.setBackground(null);
        JP.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JPanel JPin1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel JPin2 = new JPanel();
        JPanel JPin3 = new JPanel();
        JPin1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(520,33));
        //JPin1.setBackground(null);
        JP.add(JPin1);
        JPin2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(520,14));
        JP.add(JPin2);
        JPin3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(520,33));
        //JPin3.setBackground(null);
        JP.add(JPin3);
        add(JP,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        delt.setBackground(null);
        delt.setOpaque(false);
        delt.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        delt.setBorderPainted(false);
        delt.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,100));
        delt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //Filling this in later
            }
        });
        add(delt,BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        repaint();
    }
}
```

The image:

[image: DeckBack.png]

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Did you try to call setOpaque(false) on all buttons and jpanels added?

Comment: Worked! Thanks.